# Appcenter automated build fails when fetching npm packages

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg, appcenter

Appcenter automated builds were working for my react-native application and then all of a sudden stopped. The issue occurs when fetching packages using yarn and would fail on a different package each time:

> error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/node-fetch/-/node-fetch-2.6.7.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/runner/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-node-fetch-2.6.7-24de9fba827e3b4ae44dc8b20256a379160052ad-integrity/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.mjs'"
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a day or two on this and trying numerous different solutions I was able to get it working by adding this line to my [appcenter-postclone.sh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/#post-clone) script:

```sh
rm -rf /Users/runner/Library/Caches/Yarn/
```